# パッケージマネージャーコンソールにエラーが表示される

Tags: visual-studio, .net, .net-core

.NET Core のアプリケーションを作成し、プロジェクトをいったん閉じてから再度開くとパッケージマネージャーコンソールに以下のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

> 契約名 "NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.IScriptExecutor" による 1 回のエクスポートが予想されましたが、適用可能な制約の適用後に 0 が見つかりました。

.NET Framework のアプリケーションを作成した場合は、エラーメッセージは表示されません。
エラーを解消するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

拡張機能のキャッシュをクリアすることでエラーは表示されなくなりました。
具体的には、インストール済みだった「Clear MEF Component Cache」を実行しました。